# how can I install zmq in python pycharm and fix the error

Tags: python, pycharm, pyzmq

I am new to Python and Pycharm and in my project (Python 2.7) I am trying to launch some code which uses zmq as a dependency. I installed zmq through package manager and added manually some paths to env. Currently it looks like the following:

[image: paths in env]

But when I run the script in fails with the following message:  from . import 
    (constants, error, message, context,
    ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

So it looks like this:

[image: traceback]

so basically it is the first line of code which generates this error:

```
import os, sys, time, signal, zmq
```

Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you

I suppose I have Cython as when I try to install it I see the following:

[image: cmd output]

pyzmq is also present:

[image: pyzmq]

Comment: Do you have Cython installed?

Comment: I dont know, I have Anaconda2 PyCharm and Windows, maybe I should install it overthere somehow?

Comment: Try `pip install Cython` https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/install.html

Comment: I think Anaconda goes with already preinstalled Cython, pls see my update to the question

Comment: It does not come preinstalled but it might have been installed by another library you installed before. I am not sure you installed the most reliable version of zmq. COuld you uninstall it and do `pip install pyzmq` as described here. https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/

Comment: pyzmq is also installed in set of packages

Answer (score 0):

issue solved.

just installed pure Python 2.7 interpreter from https://www.python.org/ and added it as an interpreter in PyCharm, Also installed protobuf and pyzmq there and it worked. I think it was an Anaconda issue, although I removed zmq module from there leaving only pyzmq.